# Laravel GroupBy using database table column values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, laravel-5.1

I am having the following table structure in my database table:

```
+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | payable_amount | payment_type                   | created_at          |
+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+
|      10 |         450.00 | order_payment                  | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|       3 |          14.00 | moderator_commission           | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|      10 |          17.00 | principal_moderator_commission | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|       4 |          28.00 | affiliate_commission           | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|      10 |         700.00 | order_payment                  | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|       3 |          22.00 | moderator_commission           | 2016-03-28 08:21:15 |
|      10 |          26.00 | principal_moderator_commission | 2016-03-28 08:21:15 |
|       4 |          44.00 | affiliate_commission           | 2016-03-28 08:21:15 |
|      10 |          75.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|       8 |          75.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|      11 |         150.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|       7 |          75.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|      10 |         500.00 | deduction                      | 2016-03-28 09:59:22 |
|      10 |         200.00 | deduction                      | 2016-03-28 10:46:39 |
|      10 |        2500.00 | credit                         | 2016-03-28 10:54:32 |
+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+
```

What I am trying to do is I want to display the above in tabular format only but by grouping the column `payment_type` *NOT HAVING* the value of `deduction`, `credit` of the same `user_id`.

Output should be like this:

```
+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | payable_amount | payment_type                   | created_at          |
+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+
|      10 |        1150.00 | order_payment                  | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|       3 |          36.00 | moderator_commission           | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|      10 |          43.00 | principal_moderator_commission | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
|       4 |          72.00 | affiliate_commission           | 2016-03-28 08:21:14 |
       10 |          75.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|       8 |          75.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|      11 |         150.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|       7 |          75.00 | shipping                       | 2016-03-28 08:21:17 |
|      10 |         500.00 | deduction                      | 2016-03-28 09:59:22 |
|      10 |         200.00 | deduction                      | 2016-03-28 10:46:39 |
|      10 |        2500.00 | credit                         | 2016-03-28 10:54:32 |
+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+
```

The code that I have tried so far:

Controller:

```
public function fetchUser($userCode)
{
    $member = User::where('code', $userCode)->first();


    $allOrderUserPayments = OrderUserPayment::where('user_id', $member->id)
                            ->groupBy('payment_type')->get();

    return view('admin.orders.payments.user', compact('allOrderUserPayments'));
}
```

View:

```
<tr>
     <th>Details</th>
     <th>Total Wt</th>
     <th>Pay Wt</th>
     <th>Non - Pay Wt</th>
     <th>Total Amt</th>
     <th>Pay Amt</th>
     <th>Non - Pay Amt</th>
     <th>Credit</th>
     <th>Deduction</th>
     <th>Payment</th>
     <th>Balance</th>
     <th>Notes</th>
     <th>Created At</th>
</tr>
@foreach($allOrderUserPayments as $key => $order)
    <?php $credits = $balance = 0.00; ?>

    @if($order->payment_type === 'order_payment')
        <?php
        $totalOrderPaymentAmount = 0.00;
        $ordersOrderPayment = App\OrderUserPayment::where('order_code', $order->order_code)
                  ->where('user_id', $order->user_id)
                  ->where('payment_type', 'order_payment')
                  ->selectRaw('*, SUM(payable_amount) AS totalAmount')
                  ->first();

        $ordersPayableAmount = App\OrderUserPayment::where('order_code', $order->order_code)
                  ->where('user_id', $order->user_id)
                  ->where('payment_type', 'order_payment')
                  ->where('payment_payability_status', '!=', 'Non-Payable')
                  ->selectRaw('*, SUM(payable_amount) AS totalPayableAmount')
                  ->first();
         ?>
         <tr>
             <td>{{ $order->order_code }} / Order Payment</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td>{{ $ordersOrderPayment->totalAmount }}</td>
             <td>{{ $ordersPayableAmount->totalPayableAmount }}</td>
             <td>{{ number_format($ordersOrderPayment->totalAmount - $ordersPayableAmount->totalPayableAmount, 2) }}</td>
             <td>{{ $ordersOrderPayment->totalAmount }}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td>{{ $totalCredits += $ordersOrderPayment->totalAmount }}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
     @endif

     @if($order->payment_type === 'shipping')
         <?php
         $invoicer = App\OrderInvoicerShipping::where('invoicer_id', $order->user_id)->where('order_code', $order->order_code)->first();
         ?>
         <tr>
             <td>{{ $order->order_code }} / Shipping</td>
             <td>{{ $invoicer !== null ? $invoicer->weight : '' }}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td>{{ $order->payable_amount }}</td>
             <td>{{ $order->payable_amount }}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td><?php $totalCredits += ($credits += $order->payable_amount); ?>{{ $credits = $order->payable_amount }}</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             @if($order->payment_payability_status !== 'Non-Payable')
                 <td>{{ $balance += $totalCredits }}</td>
             @else
                 <td></td>
             @endif
             <td></td>
             <td>{{ $order->payment_updated_at !== null ? $order->payment_updated_at->timezone('Asia/Kolkata') : '' }}</td>
         </tr>
     @endif

     @if($order->payment_type === 'principal_moderator_commission')
         <?php
         $ordersOrderPaymentPM = App\OrderUserPayment::where('order_code', $order->order_code)
                  ->where('user_id', $order->user_id)
                  ->where('payment_type', 'principal_moderator_commission')
                  ->selectRaw('*, SUM(payable_amount) AS totalAmount')
                  ->first();

          $ordersPayableAmountPM = App\OrderUserPayment::where('order_code', $order->order_code)
                  ->where('user_id', $order->user_id)
                  ->where('payment_type', 'principal_moderator_commission')
                  ->where('payment_payability_status', '!=', 'Non-Payable')
                  ->selectRaw('*, SUM(payable_amount) AS totalPayableAmount')
                  ->first();
           ?>
           <tr>
               <td>{{ $order->order_code }} / Principal Moderator</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>{{ $ordersOrderPaymentPM->totalAmount }}</td>
               <td>{{ $ordersPayableAmountPM->totalPayableAmount }}</td>
               <td>{{ number_format($ordersOrderPaymentPM->totalAmount - $ordersPayableAmountPM->totalPayableAmount, 2) }}</td>
               <td>{{ $ordersOrderPaymentPM->totalAmount }}</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>{{ $totalCredits += $ordersOrderPaymentPM->totalAmount }}</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
       @endif

       @if($order->payment_type === 'deduction')
           <tr>
              <td>Deduction</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ $order->payable_amount }}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ $totalCredits -= $order->payable_amount }}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
           </tr>
       @elseif($order->payment_type === 'credit')
           <tr>
               <td>Credit</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>{{ $order->payable_amount }}</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>{{ $totalCredits += $order->payable_amount }}</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
       @endif
   @endforeach
```

How do I achieve this ?

**EDIT 1**: There is a `id` column in as a primary key.

**P.S.:** I know the above code is not the correct way to do fetch the desired result. I am still at the learning stage and I need some help. Kindly help me out in achieving this.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: There's no primary key in the table?

Comment: Oppss.. I forgot to add that in my table code above... Yes, it is there - the `id` column in the table..

Comment: Would an SQL only solution to get the desired result be interesting? Or just a complete laravel solution?

Comment: Preferrable is Laravel solution, but if you can give me the desired solution with SQL only, I will be able to try to tweak it on my own.. I would like to see your solution.. Please give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started with your desired result in SQL, the mapping to Laravel is unfortunately not my strong suit :)

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(payable_amount) payable_amount, 
       MAX(payment_type) payment_type, MIN(created_at) created_at
FROM orderuserpayment
GROUP BY user_id, CASE WHEN payment_type IN ('deduction', 'credit') 
                       THEN id ELSE payment_type END
ORDER BY MIN(id)
```

Basically, it gets the values in a straight forward manner (the sum of `payable_amount`, the payment type aggregated with `MAX` since it's not used as is in the `GROUP BY` and the minimum created date).

It then groups by payment type unless it's 'deduction' or 'credit', or by 'id' if it is one of them. That will keep all the deductions and credits separate and pool the others together.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cc2fd/2).

Comment: Thank you for the solution.. It worked like a charm... (Y)